# Querying Sparse Transaction History

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database schema organized as follows:

TransactionTable - One row for each transaction in the system.

LobTable - One row for each historical state of that Lob entity in the system.

So I might have Transaction rows 1, 2, 3, and 4.

In Transaction 1, 2 LobTable row were created with foreign keys to TransactionTable Row 1 (LobTable Row 1, and LobTable Row 2).

In Transaction 2, LobTable Row 1 was modified, generating a new LobTable row (LobTable Row 3) with a foreign key to TransactionTable Row 2.

In Transaction 3, LobTable Row 2 was modified, generating a new LobTable row (LobTable Row 4) with a foreign key to TransactionTable Row 3.

In Transaction 4, nothing was changed on LobTable, so no new rows were created.

Now I want to ask the question: What is the state of LobTable as of Transaction 4. The answer should be (LobTable Row 3, LobTable Row 4).

More relevantly, given a query on TransactionTable, I want to "join" it to LobTable in such a way that Transaction 4 is joined to LobTable Row 3 and 4, Transaction 3 is joined to LobTable Row 3 and 4, Transaction 2 is joined to LobTable Row 3 and 2, and Transaction 1 is joined to LobTable Row 1 and 2.

Is there a good *efficient* way to do this in SQL? Currently I have to run this entire thing through a Rollback process which pulls the data out of the database and figures out what goes with each transaction, which is not terribly efficient.

An additional more difficult question: The situation is actually somewhat worse than this. LobTable actually has 2 separate foreign keys to TransactionTable in order to handle Out-of-Sequence transaction processing in an absolutely nightmarish way. There is the main foreign key, then a foreign key that indicates what transaction overrode that row.

So for instance, take a TransactionTable with 3 transactions: Transaction 1, Transaction 2, and finally Transaction 3 which happened after Transaction 2 but is dated before it. Take an LobTable entity which has a row for each transaction that occurred. It will end up with 4 rows:

LobTable Row 1 is associated with TransactionTable Row 1 in both FKs.

LobTable Row 2 is associated with TransactionTable Row 2 in it's main FK, and TransactionTable Row 3 in it's "overriden by" FK. Importantly, this was originally generated by Transaction 2, with matching FKs, and had that secondary FK overwritten by Transaction 3. This row represents the state of the Lob entity before it was overriden by Transaction 3.

LobTable Row 3 is associated with TransactionTable Row 3 in both FKs.

LobTable Row 4 is associated with TransactionTable Row 2 in both FKs. However, this row was *generated by Transaction 3*.

Now, given this, is there a good way to unravel this, using just SQL, along with the sparse transactions specified above? It should be noted that the example above is the absolute simplest example. There could be entire chains of overridings, with each row indicating which transaction overrode it, not the transaction that generated it.

My ultimate goal is to make the data un-sparse (actually I'll be keeping the actual bulk of Lob data sparse, but adding a cross-reference table to the schema that is dense, so it is always easy to query the data as of a particular transaction), and unroll this out-of-sequence processing (so Transaction 3 above would also generate Transaction 4 to do the "correction" to Transaction 2, and not touch the data in Transaction 2). However I need to be able to process legacy data into this new format, and this old schema is giving me nightmares.

EDIT:
A more concrete example of out of sequence:
Transaction #1 is the creation of a Vehicle, with a $25,000 value, and a $1000 collision deductible. Transaction #2 has the user changing the collision deductible to $500. Transaction #3 has a change effective date before Transaction #2, and corrects the vehicle value to $20,000. As of Transaction #3 the value is $20,000, and the collision deductible is $1000.

So what does the Transaction table look like:

- Tx#1 at change effective 10/23/2018
- Tx#2 at change effective 10/30/2018
- Tx#3 at change effective 10/25/2018

What does the Vehicle table look like after Tx#1?

Veh#1:

- Transaction Tx#1
- Overridden By Tx#1
- Identifier 1
- Value $25,000
- Collision Deductible $1,000

What does the Vehicle table look like after Tx#2?

Veh#1:

- Transaction Tx#1
- Overridden By Tx#1
- Identifier 1
- Value $25,000
- Collision Deductible $1,000

Veh#2:

- Transaction Tx#2
- Overridden By Tx#2
- Identifier 1
- Value $25,000
- Collision Deductible $500

What does the Vehicle table look like after Tx#3?

Veh#1:

- Transaction Tx#1
- Overridden By Tx#1
- Identifier 1
- Value $25,000
- Collision Deductible $1,000

Veh#2:

- Transaction Tx#2
- **Overridden By Tx#3**
- Identifier 1
- Value $25,000
- Collision Deductible $500

Veh#3:

- Transaction Tx#3
- Overridden By Tx#3
- Identifier 1
- Value $20,000
- Collision Deductible $1,000

Veh#4:

- Transaction Tx#2
- Overridden By Tx#2
- Identifier 1
- Value $20,000
- Collision Deductible $500

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but this is TL;DR.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I realized this as I was writing but couldn't think of a decent way to shorten the thing. It might help if I go back and actually render HTML tables to represent the tables instead of describing them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first half of your question, I would think the most efficient way to handle this is with datetime columns that are indexed.

The LobTable state of any transaction would be the most recent LobTable row whose timestamp is equal to or less than the transaction timestamp.

I can't follow your second question in the abstract terms you used to describe it.   Some concrete sample data and desired result might help to make it clearer.

Comment: I probably should have made this clear in the question, but this is actually one of the problems: the LobTable rows are *not* timestamped. The Transaction rows are (sort of, they have datetime2 transaction dates), and the LobTable rows rely on their FK to the Transaction to figure out when they were entered. There is the actual timestamp (when was I entered in the system), and the effective date (when was this true for the business). I'll try to put together something less abstract for the second problem.